# Running Custom Actions On Uninstallation of Patch

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation, custom-action

I have a .msi that performs custom actions during installation and uninstallation.
Based on the msi, I created the patch that is not uninstallable unless you uninstall the patched application.

The problem is that when I apply the patch, the custom actions are disabled on uninstallation of the application...

To create the patch, you are supposed to create a minor upgrade msi. So, I have set the  property for each custom action when creating the minor upgrade msi.

I set the property as follows (I use installshield 2012 Pro).

```
Run during Patch Uninstall : Yes
Install Exec Sequence : ( After the InstallValidate action)
Install Exec Condition : REMOVE = "ALL"
```

But it doesn't work. What else should I be aware of when creating a patch that runs custom actions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Running custom actions on patch uninstall is a bit involved. The MSI SDK has quite a bit of information on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370739(v=vs.85).aspx . The first thing to check is that your Windows Installer version is new enough, MSI v4.5+.